# Multisite wordpress config on multidomain

Tags: multisite

I have to create multisite on wordpress network.
maindomain.com its base for all, but it only crossroad for users. Links from maindomain.com redirect to domain1.com, domain2.com and domain3.com for this tree domain i need to make wordpress network.

The biggest question is, how can i do that? All of this domain will be on the same server.

Any ideas for help mi with?

Comment: I think that's what the [wordpress-mu-domain-mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin does, but haven't tried it in anger myself.